# Update columns based on calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-update, inner-join

My table looks like this:

```
    id     entry_date          
    1      21/12/2020 15:00          
    1      21/12/2020 17:00          
    1      21/12/2020 19:00          
    2      24/12/2020 00:00         
    2      24/12/2020 12:00
```

I have a list of **id's** connected to **datestamps**. I can manage to calculate the difference between their latest and first entry as follows:

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(entry_date), MAX(entry_date))
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id;
```

However, I am unsure how I can **update** my table to reflect these calculations. What I want is the following:

```
id     entry_date          time_difference
1      21/12/2020 15:00          4
1      21/12/2020 17:00          4
1      21/12/2020 19:00          4
2      24/12/2020 00:00          12
2      24/12/2020 12:00          12
```

Comment: What's your primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can self-join:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, 
        timestampdiff(hour, min(entry_date), max(entry_date)) as time_difference
    from mytable
    group by id
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.time_difference = t1.time_difference
```

I would not necessarily recommend storing this derived information, because it is hard to keep it up to date. Instead, you can create a view. If you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
create view myview as
select t.*,
    timestampdiff(
        hour, 
        min(entry_date) over(partition by id), 
        max(entry_date) over(partition by id)
    ) as timedifference
from mytable t
```

Comment: Both this answer and Gordon Linoff's work perfectly. Thanks lads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` in the `update`:

```
update mytable t join
       (SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(entry_date), MAX(entry_date)) as diff
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY id
       ) tt
       using (id)
    set t.time_difference = tt.diff;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll accept GMB's answer as the one that solved it though, as he was slightly earlier than you.

Thanks though!